# Embedded Java Applet not displaying

Tags: java, html, deployment, applet

Attempting to embed a Java applet to an existing webpage. Code appears to be correct (at least as far as I understand it). However in FireFox, the applet simply doesn't show and in IE, I get a couple of different messages stating Java content has been restricted. Yes, Java is enabled in both browsers. My research suggests that the problem may be the web browsers simply blocking Java outright, due to the recent security concerns, however I really would like to double the code to make sure nothing is wrong with it.

Am I missing something with my code or is this the browsers refusing to display Java over security concerns?

Any thoughts?

```
<div id="links">

    <!--[if IE]><!-->
    <object classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
            codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6-windows-i586.cab" 
            type="application/x-java-applet" 
            width="700" height="30">
                <param name="code"     value="PopMenu.class" />
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <object classid="java:PopMenu.class"
            type="application/x-java-applet"
            width="700" height="30">
    <!--<![endif]-->
                <param name=labelpos   value="right" />
                <param name="src0"     value="button0.gif" />
                <param name="src1"     value="button1.gif" />
                <param name="src2"     value="button2.gif" />
                <param name="src3"     value="button3.gif" />
                <param name="text0"    value="Robert Frost on Wikipedia"/>     
                <param name="text1"    value="Robert Frost at Poets.org"/>     
                <param name="text2"    value="Robert Frost Out Loud"/>     
                <param name="text3"    value="Robert Frost: America's Poet"/>     
                <param name="href0"    value="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Frost"/>     
                <param name="href1"    value="http://www.poets.org/poet.php/prmPID/192"/>     
                <param name="href2"    value="http://robertfrostoutloud.com"/>     
                <param name="href3"    value="http://www.ketzle.com/frost"/>
    </object>

</div>
```

### EDIT

In response to the comments below; this is part of a school assignment and I have no code for the applet to post; only the .class file. It appears that I'm not the only one in class trying to figure out this issue; however the professor's only response is to write the code as the textbook teaches it. I've done that; but I still want to make sure I'm not missing something, hence why I'm asking about here.

Comment: Care to post the actual applet?

Comment: *"It appears that I'm not the only one in class trying to figure out this issue; however the professor's only response is to write the code as the textbook teaches it."*  Challenge the professor to write HTML to load the (damn) thing.  Given the Deployment Toolkit Script replaced hard coded HTML some time ago, I'm betting the applet is 'out of date' as well.  And by 'out of date' I mean ***not digitally signed.***  An unsigned applet will have p*ss all chance of being loaded in an actual modern browser, since security holes made Oracle clamp down on them.  Also..

Comment: .. please refer the instructor to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).  They should either stop teaching obsolescent, problematic technology like applets, or just plain stop teaching.